# replace text with html in jsTree

Tags: jquery, jstree

I need to change text to html in a column when using [jsTree 1.0rc2](http://www.jstree.com/) wiht jsTreeGrid. I was told that: "You might want to use the class options to assign a unique class (I know how to do that), and then find the class"

```
$("span.myClass")
```

and then change the content

```
$("span.myClass").each(function(i,elm) {
  elm = $(elm);
  var text = elm.text();
  elm.html('<a href="abc">'+text+'</a>');
});
```

could somebody help me to do the rest? I guess I need to place this code 
`$("span.myClass").each(function(i,elm) { ......` somewhere but I do not know where exactly in my code.

The author of the jsTree wrote in jsTree discussion group in regards to a similar question that "You can also build a plugin for that - checkout the themeroller plugin source. It does something similar - *modify html/classes for each loaded node*. "

```
<html>
<head>
<title> dashboard</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="_lib/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jstree.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="_lib/jstreegrid.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

$(document).ready(function(){

var data = [{
       data: "basics",
       attr: {SOF: "<a href=\"http://www.w3schools.com\">Visit W3Schools.com!</a>"},  
        children: [
         {data: "login", attr: {run: "run"},
           children: [                   
           {data: "login", attr: {}}
          ]
         } ,
         {data: "Academic Year", attr: {run: "run"},
          children: [                   
           {data: "login", attr: {}},
           {data: "Academic Year",  attr: {filter: "mini", SOF: "<a href=\"http://www.w3schools.com\">Visit W3Schools.com!</a>"}}
          ]

         }
        ]
      }];
$("div#jstree").jstree({
plugins: ["themes","json_data","grid","dnd"],
json_data: {data: data},
grid: {
        columns: [
          {width: 220, header: "Group"},
                        {cellClass: "col2", value: "run", width: 40, header: "run"},
                        {cellClass: "col3", value: "filter", width: 40, header: "filter"},
                        {cellClass: "col4", value: "SOF", width: 450, header: "SOF"}
                ]
            },
dnd: {
drop_finish : function () {
},
drag_finish : function () {
},
drag_check : function (data) {
return {
after : true,
before : true,
inside : true
};
}
}
});
});
//]]>
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="jstree"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at binding "loaded.jstree" and running your logic there, like so:

```
> jQuery("some-container")
>     .bind("loaded.jstree", function (event, data) {
>         alert("TREE IS LOADED");
>     })
>     .jstree({ /* configuration here */ });
```

For more info, look here: http://www.jstree.com/documentation/core. And a shameless plug - if you are new to jsTree and you need a quick overview, I wrote a tutorial recently, here http://tkgospodinov.com/jstree-part-1-introduction/. Hope that helps.

Comment: if I put the code where you suggest it won't work because (IMO) jsTreeGrid plugin was not fired so the class `myClass` doesn't exist. It looks like that to me. Any idea where I place the function and be sure that the plugin jsTreeGrid finished its job?